# How to implement Request Time Out in Web Application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring and If request doesn't respond in 30Sec system should show Request Time Out Page.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.info("method=doFilter, Executing TimeoutFilter");
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT);
            try {
                logger.warn("method=doFilter, Request timed out");
                ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, "Request Timed out");
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
    }, 30000);
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    timer.cancel();
}
```

My new TimerTask function is getting called after 30sec, but problem is request is still running even after I return 504 status. So, I want to return 504 and end that request, Can you please suggest a solution for this

Comment: Just configure your container appropriately and let it handle that for you. The request will keep running regardless the fact you already returned something. As mentioned let the container handle it and simply configure it accordingly.

Comment: Denium thanks for reply. So you are saying we can configure this only on container like tomcat? Is there no way to configure them on application?